# Need help finishing my school assignment where i have to make a color game

Tags: javascript, html

My assignment is to make a color game using javascript, and i don't know how to accomplish it. the premise of the assignment is to have 4 boxes with random colors and the user have to click on the one of the bottom three that matches the top box. I also have a problem where one of the boxes don’t always match.

i haven’t tried much since I don’t know where to begin, I have very little coding experience.

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");

box1.style.height = "150px";

box1.style.width = "150px";

var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");

box2.style.height = "150px";

box2.style.width = "150px";

box2.style.position = "relative";

box2.style.top = "100px";

var box3 = document.getElementById("box3");

box3.style.height = "150px";

box3.style.width = "150px";

box3.style.position = "relative";

box3.style.bottom = "50px";

box3.style.left = "150px";

var box4 = document.getElementById("box4");

box4.style.height = "150px";

box4.style.width = "150px";

box4.style.position = "relative";

box4.style.bottom = "200px";

box4.style.left = "300px";




function box1Color() {

  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";

  box1.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}



function box2Color() {

  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";

  box2.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}



function box3Color() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";

  box3.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}


function box4Color() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";

  box4.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
var init = (function() {

  box1Color();

  box2Color();

  box3Color();

  box4Color();

}());
```

```html
<h1>Fargespill v.1</h1>
<h3>Klikk på boksen nedenfor som matcher denne boksens farge </h3>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
<div id="box4"></div>
```

The expected outcome should be that one of the bottom 3 boxes match and when you click the one that matches you get a correct alert.

Comment: For school assignments that you don't understand, you're better off talking to your teacher/professor because they are the ones who know what you're expected to do. Plus, it helps them to be aware that students are struggling with things and they will be able to help better.

Comment: Also, questions along the lines of "what do I do?" are too broad for StackOverflow. Take a look at the [help], especially the section on [ask].

Comment: Specifically, what are you having a problem with?

Comment: Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1` to get a random number and get that box color and set it to the one that should match.

Comment: The user account that asked this question doesn't seem to exist anymore...

Comment: @Herohtar At a guess, maybe they weren't supposed to ask about the assignment online?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I firstly added a little script that selects a random number between 0 and 3. This number will be the box with the same color as the question.

```
correctBox = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+1;
```

While creating the question's color I saved it in a variable to use that color on the correct answer.
I also had to add the code that would check if it has to apply the correct color on the box.

```
function box1Color() {
    if(correctBox == 1){
        box1.style.backgroundColor = questionBgColor;
    }else{
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
        box1.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    }
}
```

Then I added a border in css so that you could see the lighter colors better.

```
.box{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

I added a onclick attribute to each box which would trigger a JavaScript function to check the answer.
Html:

```
<div id="box1" class="box" onclick="boxClicked(1);"></div>
```

Js:

```
function boxClicked(boxNum){
    if(boxNum == correctBox){
        //answer correct
        score++;//add one to score
        document.getElementById("score").innerText = score;
    }else{
        //wrong answer
        score--;//remove one from score
        document.getElementById("score").innerText = score;
    }
    newQuestion();
}
```

And that's it here's a snippet

```js
var correctBox;
var score = 0;
var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.style.height = "150px";
    question.style.width = "150px";
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
    box1.style.height = "150px";
    box1.style.width = "150px";
    box1.style.position = "relative";
    box1.style.top = "100px";
    var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
    box2.style.height = "150px";
    box2.style.width = "150px";
    box2.style.position = "relative";
    box2.style.bottom = "50px";
    box2.style.left = "150px";
    var box3 = document.getElementById("box3");
    box3.style.height = "150px";
    box3.style.width = "150px";
    box3.style.position = "relative";
    box3.style.bottom = "200px";
    box3.style.left = "300px";
var questionBgColor;
function boxClicked(boxNum){
 if(boxNum == correctBox){
  //answer correct
  score++;//add one to score
  document.getElementById("score").innerText = score;
 }else{
  //wrong answer
  score--;//remove one from score
  document.getElementById("score").innerText = score;
 }
 newQuestion();
}
function questionColor() {
 var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 questionBgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
 question.style.backgroundColor = questionBgColor;
} 
function box1Color() {
 if(correctBox == 1){
  box1.style.backgroundColor = questionBgColor;
 }else{
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
  box1.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
 }
}
function box2Color() {
 if(correctBox == 2){
  box2.style.backgroundColor = questionBgColor;
 }else{
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
  box2.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
 }
}
function box3Color() {
 if(correctBox == 3){
  box3.style.backgroundColor = questionBgColor;
 }else{
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
  box3.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
 }
}
function newQuestion(){
 correctBox = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+1;
 questionColor();
 box1Color();
 box2Color();
 box3Color();
}
newQuestion();
```

```css
.box{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fargespill v.1</h1>

<h3>Klikk på boksen nedenfor som matcher denne boksens farge </h3>
<div>
Your current score is: <span id="score">0</span>
</div>
<div id="question" class="box"></div>

<div id="box1" class="box" onclick="boxClicked(1);"></div>

<div id="box2" class="box" onclick="boxClicked(2);"></div>

<div id="box3" class="box" onclick="boxClicked(3);"></div>
```

And here is also a link to the jsfiddle page: https://jsfiddle.net/Etibi/9hzg0vnb/